# Swift application optional link to Mono

Tags: swift, xcode, mono

I am working on integrating some C# code into a Swift application by using Mono. This is working fine but I want to make that integration optional. So, I changed the Mono.framework linking in Xcode to be optional and confirmed that's the result in the linker command line.

Now, my question is how can I check if the Mono.framework is actually available for use? I have only seen examples that check for Objective-C classes but none that deals with standard C function availability.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using a little bit of C code:

```
extern void mono_jit_init (const char *file) __attribute__((weak_import));

int isMonoAvailable(void)
{
    return mono_jit_init != NULL;
}
```

and a header for the function as well that is included from the bridging header:

```
extern int isMonoAvailable(void);
```

With the above in place, I can call from Swift to check availability:

```
  if isMonoAvailable() {
    // do something with Mono
  }
```